# How to use async generator for streaming response chainlit

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have this simple Chainlit app:

```
import chainlit as cl

from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain_core.output_parsers import StrOutputParser
from langchain_core.runnables import RunnablePassthrough, RunnableParallel
from langchain_community.document_transformers import LongContextReorder

from lib.aws import AWSAdapter


def format_docs(docs):
    """Format the retrieved documents."""
    return "\n\n".join(doc.page_content for doc in docs)


@cl.on_chat_start
async def on_chat_start():
    adapter = AWSAdapter()

    vectordb = adapter.opensearch_client
    retriever = vectordb.as_retriever()

    prompt = PromptTemplate(
        template= \
            """Answer the question based only on the following context:
            {context}
            
            Question: {question}
            """
            ,
        input_variables=["context", "question"],
    )

    reordering = LongContextReorder()

    chain = (prompt |
             adapter.chat |
             StrOutputParser())

    rag = RunnableParallel(
        {"context": retriever | reordering.transform_documents | format_docs,
         "question": RunnablePassthrough()}
    ).assign(answer=chain)

    cl.user_session.set("rag", rag)


@cl.on_message
async def main(message: cl.Message):
    rag = cl.user_session.get("rag")

    msg = cl.Message(content="")
    await msg.send()

    async for chunk in rag.astream(message.content):
        for key in chunk:
            if key == "answer":
                await msg.stream_token(chunk[key])

    await msg.send()
```

As far as I understand, on paper all should work fine and it almost does. The problem is that I receive the final answer from my model at once and it is not streaming it token by token. I am not really familiar with async programming in Python and I am not sure why it does work in this way.

Note that

- `rag.astream(message.content)` is asynchronous python generator.
- `adapter.chat` is `langchain_community.chat_models.BedrockChat` which supports streaming

Can someone point me what the solution might be ?

P.S: this is the [only example](https://docs.chainlit.io/advanced-features/streaming) in chainlit docs which describes streaming output.

Also, I have implemented the same using synchronous generator and it works as expected.

```
output = {}
curr_key = None
for chunk in rag.stream("Question ..."):
    for key in chunk:
        if key not in output:
            output[key] = chunk[key]
        else:
            output[key] += chunk[key]
            
        if key == 'answer':
            print(chunk[key], end="", flush=True)
            
        curr_key = key
```